# Misplaced footer in exam document class

Tags: header-footer, exam

I wrote the exam below using the LaTeX exam document class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,caption,amsthm,booktabs,enumitem}
\hyphenpenalty 10000
% \usepackage[paperheight=5.8in,paperwidth=8.27in,bindingoffset=0in,left=0.8in,right=1in,
% top=0.7in,bottom=1in,headsep=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt}   %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Veuillez passer à la page suivante\ldots}{}%
}
\runningheader{\footnotesize Biostatistique}
{\footnotesize Contrôle Continu \textnumero 1}
{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ sur \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize Dr Sa\"{i}d Maanan}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Veuillez passer à la page suivante\ldots}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize Fin de l'examen}{\footnotesize Veuillez passer à la page suivante\ldots}}}
%
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
%
%
%==============================================================
\begin{document}
%%
\emergencystretch 3em
%% \thispagestyle{empty}
%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[l]{.13\textwidth}%
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo-ministere-Sante.png}
\end{minipage}%
%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{.60\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
 {\Large \bfseries ISPITS Guelmim\par
 \large Soins Infirmiers (IAR)\\[2pt]
 \large Module : Biostatistique \par}
%  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}%
%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[l]{.2\textwidth}%
\noindent
{\bfseries Nom \& Prénom}\\
\\
{\footnotesize Date: {31.10.2023}}
\end{minipage}}%
%
\par
\noindent
\uline{Durée : 2 heures   \hfill \normalsize Contrôle Continu \textnumero 1 \hfill        Note maximale: 20}
%
\begin{questions}

%\pointsinrightmargin
%\pointsdroppedatright
%\marksnotpoints
%% \marginpointname{mark}
%\pointpoints{mark}{marks}
%\pointformat{\boldmath\themarginpoints}
%\bracketedpoints
%
\vspace{1cm}
\question[03]
\label{Q:stat1}
%\pointsinmargin
Dans le cadre d'une étude sur l'impact des facteurs alimentaires sur l'age auquel les femmes connaissent leur premier cycle menstruel, l'age (en années) à la première menstruation pour un groupe de 10 femmes, qui ont suivi un régime alimentaire spécifique pendant au moins 18 mois avant les premières règles, ont été enregistrés.
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
13.6 & 13.9 & 14.0 & 14.2 & 14.9 & 15.0 & 15.0 & 15.1 & 15.4 & 16.4\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Calculez les statistiques descriptives suivantes : moyenne, variance, écart type et médiane.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\question[02]
\label{Q:stat2}
Dans le cadre d'une étude sur la transition du lycée vers l'université, les habitudes de sommeil des étudiants de première année ont été étudiées. Ci-dessous figurent les données recueillies sur le nombre d'heures de sommeil par étudiant pendant le premier semestre pour 100 étudiants de première année.
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}\toprule
\textbf{Étudiants} & 14 & 17 & 28 & 25 & 10 & 6\\
\midrule
\textbf{Heures}    & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Trouvez la moyenne et l'écart-type pour cet ensemble de données.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
%\droppoints
%
\newpage
\question[03]
\label{Q:prob1}
On a un lot de six pièces dont trois sont bonnes et trois défectueuses :
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item Combien peut-on réaliser d'échantillons différents de trois pièces ?
    \item Combien parmi ces échantillons différents contiennent trois pièces bonnes ?
    \item Combien contiennent au moins une pièce bonne ?
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
%\droppoints
%
%\newpage
\question[02]
\label{Q:prob2}
On considère deux événements $B$ et $C$ tels que: $P(B)=0.3,~P(C)=0.4,~\text{et}~ P(B|C)=\frac{1}{3}$.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Calculer les probabilités suivantes: $P(B\cap C),~P(C|B),~P(\overline{C}|B),~P(\overline{B}|C)$.
\end{enumerate}
%    \[P(B\cap C),~P(C|B),~P(\overline{C}|B),~P(\overline{B}|C)\]
%\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
%    \item Quelle est la probabilité que l'on déclare un patient malade ?
%    \item Quelle est la probabilité que l'on se trompe en déclarant qu'un patient est sain ?
%\end{enumerate}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}

%\droppoints
%%
%
\newpage
\question[05]
\label{Q:disc}
Un laboratoire de recherche sur les infections gère un échantillon de 1000 patients. On admet que chaque patient a une probabilité de 0.004 d'être infecté par un certain pathogène au cours de l'année. Soit $X$ la variable aléatoire indiquant le nombre d'infections enregistrées.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item Déterminer la loi de probabilité de $X$.
    \item Calculer $E(X)$ et $V(X)$.
    \item Peut-on faire une approximation de la loi de $X$ ? Justifier.
    \item Calculer la probabilité qu'au moins 5 patients soient infectés durant l'année ?
\end{enumerate}
%\droppoints
%%
%
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\newpage
\question[05]
\label{Q:cont}
Soit $Z$ une variable aléatoire qui suit une loi normale centrée réduite, $Z\hookrightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.\\
    Calculer les probabilités suivantes:
    \[ P(Z<1.2)~\quad~P(0.8<Z<1.2)~\quad~P(Z<-1.2)\]
    \[ P(-0.4<Z<1.5)~\quad~P(|Z|<0.92)\]
%\droppoints
%
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\newpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\captionsetup{skip=10pt}  % Adjust the skip value to add space
\caption*{Loi Normale Centrée Réduite}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & 0.0 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.04 & 0.05 & 0.06 & 0.07 & 0.08 & 0.09 \\ 
  \hline
0 & 0.5000 & 0.5040 & 0.5080 & 0.5120 & 0.5160 & 0.5199 & 0.5239 & 0.5279 & 0.5319 & 0.5359 \\ 
  0.1 & 0.5398 & 0.5438 & 0.5478 & 0.5517 & 0.5557 & 0.5596 & 0.5636 & 0.5675 & 0.5714 & 0.5753 \\ 
  0.2 & 0.5793 & 0.5832 & 0.5871 & 0.5910 & 0.5948 & 0.5987 & 0.6026 & 0.6064 & 0.6103 & 0.6141 \\ 
  0.3 & 0.6179 & 0.6217 & 0.6255 & 0.6293 & 0.6331 & 0.6368 & 0.6406 & 0.6443 & 0.6480 & 0.6517 \\ 
  0.4 & 0.6554 & 0.6591 & 0.6628 & 0.6664 & 0.6700 & 0.6736 & 0.6772 & 0.6808 & 0.6844 & 0.6879 \\ 
  0.5 & 0.6915 & 0.6950 & 0.6985 & 0.7019 & 0.7054 & 0.7088 & 0.7123 & 0.7157 & 0.7190 & 0.7224 \\ 
  0.6 & 0.7257 & 0.7291 & 0.7324 & 0.7357 & 0.7389 & 0.7422 & 0.7454 & 0.7486 & 0.7517 & 0.7549 \\ 
  0.7 & 0.7580 & 0.7611 & 0.7642 & 0.7673 & 0.7704 & 0.7734 & 0.7764 & 0.7794 & 0.7823 & 0.7852 \\ 
  0.8 & 0.7881 & 0.7910 & 0.7939 & 0.7967 & 0.7995 & 0.8023 & 0.8051 & 0.8078 & 0.8106 & 0.8133 \\ 
  0.9 & 0.8159 & 0.8186 & 0.8212 & 0.8238 & 0.8264 & 0.8289 & 0.8315 & 0.8340 & 0.8365 & 0.8389 \\ 
  1.0 & 0.8413 & 0.8438 & 0.8461 & 0.8485 & 0.8508 & 0.8531 & 0.8554 & 0.8577 & 0.8599 & 0.8621 \\ 
  1.1 & 0.8643 & 0.8665 & 0.8686 & 0.8708 & 0.8729 & 0.8749 & 0.8770 & 0.8790 & 0.8810 & 0.8830 \\ 
  1.2 & 0.8849 & 0.8869 & 0.8888 & 0.8907 & 0.8925 & 0.8944 & 0.8962 & 0.8980 & 0.8997 & 0.9015 \\ 
  1.3 & 0.9032 & 0.9049 & 0.9066 & 0.9082 & 0.9099 & 0.9115 & 0.9131 & 0.9147 & 0.9162 & 0.9177 \\ 
  1.4 & 0.9192 & 0.9207 & 0.9222 & 0.9236 & 0.9251 & 0.9265 & 0.9279 & 0.9292 & 0.9306 & 0.9319 \\ 
  1.5 & 0.9332 & 0.9345 & 0.9357 & 0.9370 & 0.9382 & 0.9394 & 0.9406 & 0.9418 & 0.9429 & 0.9441 \\ 
  1.6 & 0.9452 & 0.9463 & 0.9474 & 0.9484 & 0.9495 & 0.9505 & 0.9515 & 0.9525 & 0.9535 & 0.9545 \\ 
  1.7 & 0.9554 & 0.9564 & 0.9573 & 0.9582 & 0.9591 & 0.9599 & 0.9608 & 0.9616 & 0.9625 & 0.9633 \\ 
  1.8 & 0.9641 & 0.9649 & 0.9656 & 0.9664 & 0.9671 & 0.9678 & 0.9686 & 0.9693 & 0.9699 & 0.9706 \\ 
  1.9 & 0.9713 & 0.9719 & 0.9726 & 0.9732 & 0.9738 & 0.9744 & 0.9750 & 0.9756 & 0.9761 & 0.9767 \\ 
  2.0 & 0.9772 & 0.9778 & 0.9783 & 0.9788 & 0.9793 & 0.9798 & 0.9803 & 0.9808 & 0.9812 & 0.9817 \\ 
  2.1 & 0.9821 & 0.9826 & 0.9830 & 0.9834 & 0.9838 & 0.9842 & 0.9846 & 0.9850 & 0.9854 & 0.9857 \\ 
  2.2 & 0.9861 & 0.9864 & 0.9868 & 0.9871 & 0.9875 & 0.9878 & 0.9881 & 0.9884 & 0.9887 & 0.9890 \\ 
  2.3 & 0.9893 & 0.9896 & 0.9898 & 0.9901 & 0.9904 & 0.9906 & 0.9909 & 0.9911 & 0.9913 & 0.9916 \\ 
  2.4 & 0.9918 & 0.9920 & 0.9922 & 0.9925 & 0.9927 & 0.9929 & 0.9931 & 0.9932 & 0.9934 & 0.9936 \\ 
  2.5 & 0.9938 & 0.9940 & 0.9941 & 0.9943 & 0.9945 & 0.9946 & 0.9948 & 0.9949 & 0.9951 & 0.9952 \\ 
  2.6 & 0.9953 & 0.9955 & 0.9956 & 0.9957 & 0.9959 & 0.9960 & 0.9961 & 0.9962 & 0.9963 & 0.9964 \\ 
  2.7 & 0.9965 & 0.9966 & 0.9967 & 0.9968 & 0.9969 & 0.9970 & 0.9971 & 0.9972 & 0.9973 & 0.9974 \\ 
  2.8 & 0.9974 & 0.9975 & 0.9976 & 0.9977 & 0.9977 & 0.9978 & 0.9979 & 0.9979 & 0.9980 & 0.9981 \\ 
  2.9 & 0.9981 & 0.9982 & 0.9982 & 0.9983 & 0.9984 & 0.9984 & 0.9985 & 0.9985 & 0.9986 & 0.9986 \\ 
  3.0 & 0.9987 & 0.9987 & 0.9987 & 0.9988 & 0.9988 & 0.9989 & 0.9989 & 0.9989 & 0.9990 & 0.9990 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{questions}
% \begin{center}
%  \rule{.5\textwidth}{1pt}
% \end{center}
\end{document}
```

When I generate the pdf it looks fine (see page 2 below for example):

[image]

However, whenever I print it the footer is located far higher than where it should be located:
[image]

Does anyone know what causes this? And how can I fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This is probably due to your PDF viewer/print driver.  It prints fine for me.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Oh ok, I will try another printer, thank you very much.

Comment: The teacher's edition of Acrobat was way too expensive, but the drivers that came with it were almost worth it.